# Fedora 18 Disable Hibernate and Suspend

Tags: linux, fedora, sleep, hibernate, lxde

I recently installed the new Fedora 18, LXDE spin on a workstation (not a laptop).

I want to disable the hibernate and suspend functions, and remove them from the "Logout" menu in the UI.

In F17 and earlier, this was easily done by adding a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-disable-suspend.pkla` with the contents:

```
[Disable Suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate;org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Doing so would remove the menu entries, leaving Logout, Reboot, Shutdown and Cancel.

I also found instructions to modify the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy`, changing two values to:

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

Neither works for F-18.

The problem with the latter approach for F17 and earlier was that the file might be overwritten when upower is updated, but even that would be acceptable.

Removing `pm-utils` also seemed ideal, but I can't remove `pm-utils` because `libvirt` indirectly depends on it.

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page:

> The polkit Local Authority no longer exists. Existing configuration files are honored; see pkla-admin-identities(8) and
>          pkla-check-authorization(8) for description of the configuration format.

I'm pretty sure "existing configuration files are honored" is a lie.

The [Arch Linux wiki page for Polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Disable_suspend_and_hibernate) shows a new way:

> The following rule disables suspend and hibernate for all users.
>
> ```
> /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-disable-suspend.rules
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
>     if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions") {
>         return polkit.Result.NO;
>     }
> });
> ```

That rule works for me on Fedora 19.

Answer (score -1):

> The problem with the latter approach for F17 and earlier was that the
>   file might be overwritten when upower is updated, but even that would
>   be acceptable.

U can protect those files from overwriting by setting 'i' attribute (chattr +i /path/to/file), doing this as root of course.

Comment: If editing that file achieved the desired end for F18, this would be an option.  Alas, it does not work.

Comment: Ok, if you don't need hiberbate and susnend - just remove "pm-utils" from system, and those items will be gone.

Comment: I considered that.  `libvirt` depends on it (via `libvirt-client`) so that is a no-go.  It also wants to remove `lxde-common` which doesn't look very helpful.  I'll edit the question to indicate this.